# Maxima/minima of $f(x)=\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{2} Nx) }{\sin(\frac{1}{2} x)}.$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, optimization

How do I find: the $\bf maxima$ and  minima  of the function $f$ with $ f$ given by:
$$f(x)=\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{2} Nx) }{\sin(\frac{1}{2} x)},  \;\;(N=1,2,3...)$$

What I did, is:
Minima: I set: $\sin(\frac{1}{2} Nx)=0$

Can someone please tell me whether my method is right (and maybe provide me some more background)? I hope you can help.

Comment: It seems that you assume that the first minimum of f(x) will be zero. This does not look right.

Comment: The maximum and minimum of f(x) correspond to the values of x which make the derivative equal to zero. How does look your derivative ? Is there an obvious solution ?

Comment: To make your life easier, may I suggest you replace "x" by "2 y" ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Can you please tell me the general idea behind your method?

Comment: What is the limit of your derivative for x=0 ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici you would get 0/0 for x=0. That's (part) of my problem ;).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici So I would say the limit is undefined for x=0

Comment: This looks like a problem related to diffraction on a grating. Didn't you forget to square your function to get intensity out of amplitude?

Answer (score 1):

Try L'Hopital's rule. The limit is zero and x=0 corresponds to a maximum. What is the value of f(x) when x->0 ?

Comment: It is N. But still, the general approach isn't clear to me. Can you list your steps please?